# java jdbc select from where with string type

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to solve a problem of my code. In the following code, it contains `JComboBox` which have a list of month. When I click on January, I want to show all the details of that month.

```
private void jComboBox1_MonthsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
  String selection = (String)jComboBox1_Months.getSelectedItem();
     if(selection.equals("January")){
        try{

          String sql = "select * from booking where Date = ??/01/??"; //problem
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();
          viewBookingTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
          } catch(Exception e){

          }     
     }
}
```

The format for the `Date` is `12/01/16` in the `Database` with type `CHAR`.
Please help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I suggest revisiting your aprroach and favor the usage of the `java.sql.Date` type, you can select the desired rows using a ***LIKE*** predicate:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE Date LIKE '%/01/%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo could do that:

> String sql = "select * from booking where SUBSTR(Date,4,2) = "01";

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = jComboBox1_Months.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `date` like '%?%';
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setObject(1, index);
...
```